# The "getnodevalue" of HTMLUNIT not working on domattr

Tags: htmlunit

every time i want to get the Value of my DomAttr i get an TypeError:

My Code:

```
Wanted = page.getByXPath("//span[contains(.,'Some')]/parent::a/@href");
```

return this

```
[DomAttr[name=href value=URLSTRING]]
```

Now i want to geht the value (=URLSTRING) with Wanted.getNodeName();
but every Time i get the Error

```
Cannot find function getNodeValue in object [DomAttr[name=href value=
```

same when i use getValue

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things that make no sense in the code (particularly, because it is not complete). However, I think I can guess what the issue is.

`getByXPath` is actually returning a List (funny thing you missed the part of the code in which you specify it as a list and replaced it with a `Wanted`).

Note you should probably also have type warnings in the code too.

Now, you can see that the returned value is in square brackets. That means it is a List (confirming first assumption).

Finally, although you happened to miss that part of the code too, I guess you are directly applying the `getValue` to the list instead of the DomAttr elements in the list.

How to solve it: If you need more than 1 result iterate over the elements of the list (that `Wanted` word over there). If you need 1 result then user the `getFirstByXPath` method.

Were my guesses right?

Comment: Any Help? What i have to do?

Comment: i have only remove the var bevor Wanted

Comment: Yeay, that is it.
Was a List an with getFirstBayXPath i get only one Value and now .getValue() is working ...

Thank you very much ;)